# parallelize external program in python call?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have an external program which I can not change.
It reads an input file, does some calculations, and writes out a result file. I need to run this for a million or so combinations of input parameters.
The way I do it at the moment is, that I open a template file, change some strings in it (to input the new parameters), write it out, start the program using os.popen(), read the output file, do a chisquare test on the result, and then I restart with a different set of parameters.

The external program is only running on one core, so I tried to split my parameters space up and started multiple instances in different folders. Different folders were necessary because the program overwrites its output file. This works, but it still took about ~24 hours to finish.

Is it possible to run this as seperate processes without the result file being overwritten? Or do you see any other thing I could do to speed this up?

Thx.

Comment: If this program is doing it's calculations fast (like it seems) IO dominates everything, so that parallel calls are not helping much (HDD too slow). If possible, use the program without writing files, e.g. using stdin, stdout.

Comment: I timed the individual steps in my script, and running the external program takes about 10 times as much as the io steps combined. If I start 7 instances manually, it finishes (for a test) in 20 minutes instead of 3.5 hours. So I could probably start much more instances before io gets relevant. But how I can do this automatically without having the outputfile overwritten by a different running process? Is it possible to load an instance into some kind of virual area that is unique to each instance?